# JQuery UI tab won't work until a tab is clicked twice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery ui tabs with the script below:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tab_index = $('#tab_index').attr('value');
    $('#tabs').tabs({ cache:true,
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
            }
        },
    });
    $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', tab_index);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="tab_index" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tab_index; ?>" />

<div id = "tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="tabs/current_portfolio.php">Current Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="tabs/realised_gain_loss.php">Realised Gain / Loss</a></li>
    <li class = "tab_trade_list"><a href="tabs/add_trades.php">Add Trades</a></li>
    <li><a href="tabs/test.php">Test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Where `$tab_index` is a numeric value generated dynamically from a PHP script based on different scenarios.

The strange thing is that when the page is loaded, I need to click on a tab twice before it is selected, but it would work normally after that, until the page is refreshed and the problem returns. Any idea of how to resolve this will be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: What do the <li> elements in your <div id="tabs"><ul></ul></div> look like?

Comment: Hi Jason, please find the <li> elements in the edited question above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use tabs in conjunction with ajax content but comparing your example against the demo example at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax I see a few things:

You have `$('#tabs').tabs({ cache:true,` but I don't see that as part of the [tabs api](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Looks like you are loading the fist tab via ajax as well?  Is that part of the problem?
When you initially load the page and click a tab does firebug or the IE developer tools tell you anything is wrong?

In response to your comment below...I use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var setTab = $("#setTab").val();
    $("#iTABs").tabs("select", setTab);
})
```

In conjunction with this (on page tabs.php):

```
<div id="iTABs">
    <ul>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#tabs-1">Tab Title</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#tabs-2">Tab 2 Title</a></li>
        <!-- Repeat for each tab you need -->
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1">Fancy tab content</div>
<div id="tabs-2">Fancy tab 2 content</div>
<input type="hidden" id="setTab" value="<?php echo $_GET['sTab'];  //2 ?>">
```

With that when a user goes to `tabs.php?sTab=2` The tab strip opens to Tab 2 and the tab 2 content is shown.  No fancy ajax stuff there...

Also, (not part of the issue but just in general) you use:

```
var tab_index = $('#tab_index').attr('value');
```

You could just use:

```
var tab_index = $('#tab_index').val();
```

Comment: I tried firebug but I am not told of any problem when the page is loaded and clicking a tab...I also tried removing the ajaxoptions bit, it still doesn't help...

Comment: What I am trying to do basically is to have a specific tab open by default when the tabbed page is loaded from a defined previous page. Any idea of how this can be done?

Comment: @Wil See my changed answer above

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you so very much for the help, unfortunately it still doesn't work, it seems that whenever any tab is clicked, the page reloads and the default tab is set to whatever the $_GET['sTab'] value is, as a result, it get stuck in the default tab and all other tabs are not selectable. Until cache is set to true, the tabs become selectable but only when they are clicked twice...

Comment: Got it working finally! Thank you so much Jason for your halp!!